# cuando compilo me remite este [Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, c

Cuando compilo me tira un error en la linea strupr, supongo que la variable char no es compatible con strupr sin embargo no se me ocurre otra macomo solucionarlo. Estoy tratando de que el programa transforme todas las letras de mi archivo de texto en mayúsculas.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;
    void lectura();
    
    int main (){
        lectura ();
        
        system ("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    void lectura (){
        
        ifstream archivo;
        string texto;
        
        archivo.open("escritura.txt",ios::in);
        
        if(archivo.is_open()){
            char c;
            
            while(!archivo.eof()){
                
                 
                 c= archivo.get();
               
                cout <<c;
             strupr(c);
            }
            
              
            archivo.close();
            
            
        } else 
        {cout <<"no se pudo abrir el archivo";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Por favor elige, C++ o C a secas? algo va de uno al otro; usa la etiqueta correcta y retira la otra. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: `strupr` modifica un `char[]` para que todos los caracteres sean en mayuscula. Tu le estas dando un solo caracter. Lo que puedes hacer es `c = toupper(c);`

Comment: muchas gracias @Pablochaches muy util tu respuesta, me sirvio y pude terminar el codigo correctamente.